# Calculate the Probability in competition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> The committee RAM competition knows from experience that the probability of successfully 
>   Contest is 0.95 for the student who has grade  "very good" in BAC test , 0.5 
>   one who has 'Good' in  BAC test  and 0.2 for others. He believes, moreover, 
>   that among the candidates to contest RAM 2014, 35% grade "very good" and 50% 
>   were marked "Good".

- If we consider a applicant  2014 randomly, having succeeded the RAM competition, the 
  probability that he  did not grade "very good" or "good" is:

Indeed,

> As Mr Graham Kemp said i have to find 
>   $\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathbb P}}$
>   $$\begin{align}\P(\neg(G\cup V)\mid S) & = \frac{\P(S \cap \neg(G\cup V))}{\P(S)} \\ &  \end{align}$$

Indeed,
$$\begin{align*}\P(\neg(G\cup V)\mid S) & = \frac{\P(S \cap \neg(G\cup V))}{\P(S)} \\ 
&=\frac{\P(S / \neg(G\cup V))\P(\neg(G\cup V))}{\P(S)}\\
&=\frac{\P(S / \neg(G\cup V))(1-\P( G\cup V))}{\P(S)}\\  
&=\frac{\P(S / \neg(G\cup V))(1-(\P( G)+\P(V)-\P(G\cup V)))}{\P(S)}\\ 
\end{align*}$$
as we 've $\P(G\cup V)=\P(G/V)\P(V)$ or  $\P(G\cup V)=\P(V/G)\P(G)$
$$\begin{align*}
&=\frac{\P(S / \neg(G\cup V))(1-(\P( G)+\P(V)-\P(G/V)\P(V)))}{\P(S)}\\ 
&=\frac{\P(S / \neg(G\cup V))(1-(\P( G)+\P(V)-\P(V/G)\P(G)))}{\P(S)}\\ 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hard to know, but you may be on the wrong track. Let $S$ be the event the person was successful. We want the **conditional** probability $\Pr(O|S)$.

Comment: Indeed.  "...not grade 'very good' or 'good'" is "...did grade other." ($\overline{VG\cup G} = \bar {VG} \cap \bar G$)  Further "given success" means you are after the conditional probability.  $P(O\mid S)$

Comment: Use \cap for "and", \cup for "or", \mid for "given".  Otherwise it looks good, except that grades for the one test are *mutually exclusive*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The committee RAM competition knows from experience that the probability of successfully Contest is 0.95 for the student who has grade "very good" in BAC test , 0.5 one who has 'Good' in BAC test and 0.2 for others. He believes, moreover, that among the candidates to contest RAM 2014, 35% grade "very good" and 50% were marked "Good".
>
> •If we consider a applicant 2014 randomly, having succeeded the RAM competition, the probability that he did not grade "very good" or "good" is:

$\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathbb P}}$
You are given:
$$\begin{align}
\P(S\mid V)&=0.95 \\ \P(S\mid G)&= 0.5 \\ \P(S\mid \neg (G\cup V)) &= 0.2 \\ \P(V)&= 0.35 \\ \P(G) &= 0.50\end{align}$$
You need to find:$$\begin{align}\P(\neg(G\cup V)\mid S) & = \frac{\P(S \cap \neg(G\cup V))}{\P(S)} \\ & \ddots \end{align}$$

---

Addressing the modification to the original question after this.

> $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\P(\neg(G\cup V)\mid S) & = \frac{\P(S \cap \neg(G\cup V))}{\P(S)} \\[1ex]
> &=\frac{\P(S \mid \neg(G\cup V))\P(\neg(G\cup V))}{\P(S)}\\[1ex]
> &=\frac{\P(S \mid \neg(G\cup V))(1-\P( G\cup V))}{\P(S)}\\[1ex]  
> &=\frac{\P(S \mid \neg(G\cup V))(1-(\P( G)+\P(V)-\P(G\color{blue}{\cap} V)))}{\P(S)}
> \end{align}$$

Good so far, but as grades are **mutually exclusive** (a student can only receive one): $\P(G\cap V) = 0$

That simplifies it to: $\P(\neg(G\cup V)) = 1-\bigl(\P(G)+\P(V)\bigr)$
$$\begin{align}\P(\neg(G\cup V)\mid S) & = 
\frac{\P(S \mid \neg(G\cup V))\,\Bigl(1-\bigl(\P(G)+\P(V)\bigr)\Bigr)}{\P(S)} 
\end{align}$$

Just use the **law of total probability** on the denominator.

Comment: please i'll update my answer and check it please if am i right or wrong

Comment: That is okay, @Educ.  I'll check back later and see how you are doing.

Comment: @Educ  And done.